# JS: Iterate through the key, value pairs of an Object

Tags: javascript, loops

I'm working on a Django framework project where I create a variable in Python to be a dict like:

```
dict = {
   ('ABC', 'XYZ'): [
      ('a', 'A'), 
      ('b', 'B'), 
      ('c', 'C'), 
      ....
   ]
}
```

and I am including this data into an HTML's data-attribute when I render the page. When I grab this data in JS is when it gets difficult for me because JS only recognizes tuples like arrays I believe. I need to loop through this object in JS to create my HTML code. Trying something like `console.log(Object.entries(obj))` creates thousands of arrays.

In pseudo code, I'm trying to accomplish:

```
function init(section) {

   var test1 = [...create HTML code....]

   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

      $(section).append(test1)

      resolve()
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var section = $("#PageFilter")
    var filters = $(section).data("filters")

    for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(filters)) {
     
       init(section).then(function () {
   
          for (let x = 0; x < value.length; x++) {
      
             var test2 = [...create some more HTML code...]

             $('find_test1').append(test2)
      
          }
      }
   }
})
```

**UPDATE**
Here is a sample of the DOM element's data attribute I was storing

```
<div 
   class="ms-auto py-4" 
   id="PageFilter" 
   data-filters="{('Region', 'cardinal'): [('EAST', 'EAST'), ('WEST', 'WEST')], ('State', 'state'): [('AL', 'AL'), ('AR', 'AR'), ('GA', 'GA'), ('KY', 'KY'), ('MS', 'MS'), ('NC', 'NC'), ....], ('Instatllation Type', 'installation_type'): [('BUILDING', 'Building'), ('EXTERNAL SERVICE', 'External Service'), ...]}"
></div>
```

Comment: give some shorter sample of console.log output or change tags to python

Comment: How do you pass it to JavaScript?

Comment: @jabaa -  Django is a web framework that is python-based, so everything I do to create the framework of a webpage is in python; however, once the web page has been rendered, you use javascript and JQuery to grab anything from the DOM.


I have a data-attribute from a <div> I am grabbing in JS (in a `document.ready(function(){})`) that contains "my_python_dict" and I am using that data to loop through and create more HTML code from it

Comment: You can't send Python dictionaries over the network. You can only send text (or bytes). How do you convert a Python dictionary to something JavaScript can read. My question is, how do you serialize the dictionary and what text is actually send from the server to the client.

Comment: @jabaa - maybe I am not serializing the data correctly then. I was using a DOM element's data attribute to pass the text over.

Comment: What is the actual text? Can you post it in the question? Post a [mcve] and not pseudo code, a snippet that I can copy and paste to reproduce your problem.

Comment: @jabaa - I see. I added an update to the question to give you insight. I am basically trying to create a filter that has a header (the key) and it options to filter (the values). The reason I use a tuple for the key and values is because one index is for the label the user sees displayed and the other index is the .value() that is used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251050/discussion-between-franklin-and-jabaa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some clarification, I realize HTML's data attributes were only storing text, and the string was not in the JSON format to be parsed.

I was able to obtain the object in JS by doing a couple of things:

1. I changed my python dict to the format
   `{'key': (tuple), 'value': [(tuple), (tuple)]}`
   ...so that JS can distinguish the key, value pair in its object.
2. I made sure I was using `json.dumps(my_python_dict)` when I was rendering the page to capture it in JSON.